# WinForms and DevExpress GridControl - how to disable default panel filter

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have application in VS written in C# and WinForms. I use DevExpress and I have grid with default filter that is enabled like it's shown below (Enter text to search and buttons Find and Clear):
[image]

The grid that is used is: DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl
How to disable this default filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have the ColumnViewOptionsFind.AlwaysVisible set to true, when it should be false.

see https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnViewOptionsFind.AlwaysVisible.property